# Adding a database populated dropdown Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix, html.dropdownlistfor

just started learning to make dynamic pages with WebMatrix and have run into a road block.  (Long history of static html and some php using notepad++, but this is new to me.)

In short: I'm trying to give people the option of creating a new team entry in the database OR joining an existing team from a html helper dropdown list populated from the database.  I've been trying various ways of doing this for the better part of two days and can't seem to figure it out after extensive searchers here and on ASP.net.  I'm also hoping to figure out how to allow either the creation of a new team or joining an existing team already in the DB on the same page without getting commas inserted into the database.

I've removed all my attempts at a dropdown and am sharing what currently works without the html.dropdown:

```
@{
    Validation.RequireField("FName", "Your first name is required");
    Validation.RequireField("LName", "Your last name is required");
    Validation.RequireField("Team", "A team is required to play");
    Validation.RequireField("Pledge", "You must donate to play.");

    var db = Database.Open("BBBT");
    var FName = Request.Form["FName"];
    var LName = Request.Form["LName"];
    var Team = Request.Form["Team"];
    var Pledge = Request.Form["Pledge"];

    if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid()) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Players (FName, LName, Team, Pledge) " +
                "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)";
            db.Execute(insertQuery, FName, LName, Team, Pledge);
            Response.Redirect("~/ListTeams");
        }

    }
}
```

....Snip....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Register</h1>

 @Html.ValidationSummary("Errors with your submission:")

 <form method="post" action="">
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Join the fun!</legend>
     <div>
       <label>First Name:</label>
       <input name="FName" type="text" size="50" value="@FName" />
      </div>
      <div>
       <label>Last Name:</label>
       <input name="LName" type="text" size="50" value="@LName" />
     </div>
     <div>
       <label>Create a Team</label>
       <input name="Team" type="text" size="50" value="@Team" />
        </div>
       <div>
       <label>Or Joing an Existing Team</label>
<!-- This is where I would like to put the Dropdown list-->
        @Html.DropDownList
        </div>
     <div>
       <label>Pledge:</label>
       <input name="Pledge" type="text" size="50" value="@Pledge" />
     </div>
     <div>
       <label>&nbsp;</label>
       <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="submit" />
     </div>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: This is labeled MVC but I don't see your controller or where your using the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your will be getting the result in two steps. First Generate the List, then display it.

In the code block at the top of the page add this code

```
List<string> Teams = new List<string>();
foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT Team FROM Players"))
{
Teams.Add(row.Team);
}
```

and in the place you want the dropdown populate the list

```
<select name="Team">
@foreach(string Teamname in Teams)
{
<option value="@Teamname ">@Teamname </option>
}
</select>
```

EDIT:

```
<select name="Team" id="TeamDropdown" onchange="toggleteamcreation()">
    @foreach(string Teamname in Teams)
    {
        <option value="@Teamname ">@Teamname </option>
    }
    <option value"New">Create New Team</option>
</select>
<script>
function toggleteamcreation(){
    if(document.getElementById('TeamDropdown').value=="New"){
        document.getElementById('Create_New_Team').style.display="block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('Create_New_Team').style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>
<div id="Create_New_Team" style="display:none">
   <label>Create a Team</label>
   <input name="Team" type="text" size="50" value="@Team" />
</div>
```

Comment: Abhishek, Thank you!  I think we're going in the right direction here.  Unfortunately, I get a "CS0136 CS0136: A local variable named 'Team' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Team', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else" error.  I've tried to swap out team for the table name and various other options, but still get the error on the line with "@foreach(string Team in Teams)

Comment: My mistake i didn't realized i was using the name "Team" twice concurrently in the same scope. Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i just need to figure out how to allow it to either  create a team or join a team, rather than doing both with the same form. Much appreciated!

Comment: I have edited the answer to fullfill your request.. Change your question accordingly. also mark the question as solved if the query is fullfilled.

Comment: Ohh, wow.  I wasn't expecting you to answer that too!  Thanks so much.